# Running 'systemctl daemon-reload' Has No Effect

Tags: rhel, systemd, systemctl, kubernetes

I have scoured google for why this might be happening, but was not able to find an answer and thought I might get some insight here.

I have a systemd service file that was installed via yum `/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service`. I have **NOT** made any changes to the file. I am simply trying to start and enable the service with the following.

```
# systemctl enable kubelet.service
# systemctl start kubelet.service
```

I get the following message.

```
Warning: kubelet.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

When I run the above reload command, everything seems to complete pretty quick with no output. Unfortunately, the kubelet.service is still registering as modified. I also tried the command `systemctl --system daemon-reload` with no luck. I've also tried rebooting and re-running the reload commands, uninstalling kubernetes packages and reinstalling all with no success.

Just for kicks I modified a different service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`, did a `systemctl daemon-reload`, and the docker service behaves just fine via systemctl.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Put the outout of of your kubelet unit sevice

Comment: Is there a file in /etc/systemd/system for kubelet that's getting modified? Does `systemctl show kubelet | grep ^FragmentPath` show /usr/lib... or /etc/systemd/... ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the link where I saw this, but it's a known bug in a particular version of systemd with services that uses a config directory (ex. /use/lib/systemd/system/<service-name>.d). I'm having it happen to me with kubernetes on RHEL 7.7.

Comment: Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3123). I'm going to try updating systemd to see if that fixes things.